# How to document the failing JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit, web-api-testing

I have developed an Automation framework with JUnit for our API Testing. Here I have created a separate class for each API listing multiple unit tests for that API.
I want to list each failing JUnit test case in some separate file so that I can easily track the failing test cases. Can anyone suggest how can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean with `develop a JUnit framework`, why not using JUnit itself ? Why not simply use Continuous Integration such as Jenkins, then you have a regular report about succeeding and failing tests ?!

Comment: I would suggest to use you code in a maven project and run the tests via the surefire plugin, then you get a nice summary.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @EmersonC Yeh! It's JUnit itself. Plus I have added other classes which contains common code for API calls, Data reading and response assertion. I will explore Jenkins as well as surefire plugin as suggested by SubOptimal. And it's already a maven project. Thanks guys!

Comment: @NeeteshKumarGupta If it's already a maven project, then a simple `mvn test` would normally run your tests. If some tests were failed you the a summary at the end.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I replaced the JUnit with TestNG, Integrated the Surefire plug-in and Jenkins CI as well, and my framework is working the same that I intended in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I replaced the JUnit with TestNG, Integrated the Surefire plug-in and Jenkins CI as well, and my framework is working the same that I intended in the beginning.